# android login facebook userid and username

Tags: android, facebook

i wrote code witch can to login facebook and show userID and userName.it's working but i have one problem when i logined i must click Login button double to go next activity(i want when i logined automaticly should start new activity)
this is a my code

```
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

            getProfileInformation();
            if (isBoolean == true) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ChooseLocation.class);

                in.putExtra("ID", id.getText().toString());
                in.putExtra("NAME", name.getText().toString());

                startActivity(in);
            }
            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                            try {

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {

                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    public void getProfileInformation() {

        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    final String id = profile.getString("id");

                    final String name = profile.getString("name");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Name: " + name + "\n:id " + id,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            LoginFacebook.this.name.setText(name);
                            LoginFacebook.this.id.setText(id);
                            isBoolean = true;

                        }

                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: start new activity in onCompleted method.

Comment: i tryed but not working :(